# Including non-Python files with setup.py

Tags: python, distutils

How do I make `setup.py` include a file that isn't part of the code? (Specifically, it's a license file, but it could be any other thing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files is all you should need.

Since you mentioned a license file, you can include additional meta-data (such as a license) [this way](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data).

Comment: 'data_files' is kinda broken I think, because it installs the files in a system-wide location, not associated with my project files, and this location *changes* depending on whether the user installs my package using "setup.py install" or "pip install". So my code can't then find the files. I guess I could try to search both locations at runtime. Do people really do this?